# Blade embedded components

Tags: laravel, templates, laravel-blade

In some applications, I have very small blade templates that I only use in one single template.

Unfortunately I still need to create a separated file such as:

Component `jumbotron`:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-4">{{ $title }}</h1>
  {{ $slot }}
</div>
```

In my main component I then use:

```
@component('jumbotron', ['title' => 'Foo'])
Hello World!
@endcomponent
```

I would like to find a way to embed my component in my template such as:

```
@template('jumbotron')
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-4">{{ $title }}</h1>
  {{ $slot }}
</div>    
@endtemplate

@component('jumbotron', ['title' => 'Foo'])
Hello World!
@endcomponent
```

I this somehow possible?

Comment: Do you use the component multiple times in this single template or only once?

Comment: Yes multiple times

Comment: I don't think this is possible out of the box. You would have to manually add a `@template` directive by extending blade to make this work, but this approach seams a bit overkill in comparison to creating a file :-/